FireFox sending HTTP3 PING packets every 15s long after all tabs are closed
I noticed some strange network activity so I did some investigation. My FireFox browser is sending HTTP/3, QUIC PING packets to a site that I left at least an hour ago. It is not a shady site but I know there are firewall(s) in between. Not only it is sending PING every 15s, it is getting response from the server too. I think that explains why the connection is still alive. But I have no tabs open to that site. Shouldn't FireFox cease all communication? Is it normal for HTTP/3?

I'll bet it's keeping a connection alive for web push notifications you subscribed to on that site.

Did you allow notifications on that website? Alternatively, but I'm not too sure about that, it may have set up a service worker that runs in the background after you closed the tabs (for notifications or otherwise).
The Notifications API may run outside of your traditional tab website context:

These are outside the top-level browsing context viewport, so therefore can be displayed even when the user has switched tabs or moved to a different app.


the Notifications API spec specifies a number of additions to the ServiceWorker API, to allow service workers to fire notifications.

Service Workers may run in the background and offline:

They will also allow access to push notifications and background sync APIs.

When you open the About Service Workers page in Firefox by entering about:serviceworkers in the address bar you can see and unregister service workers. If you find a service worker for that website, and unregister it, that's a good test case for whether it's the cause of your observation.
